# Android - Signing an apk

Tags: android

I have written a little program, by default, it is signed with debug certificate.
I checked the documentation at Android developer site, I don't know how to get the certificate and key, could someone advice me?

Comment: Are you having map also in ur app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click your project:

Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package

1. Give the project name which you want to sign. Click next.
2. If you want to create a new keystore, select "Create New Keystore".
3. Give the location where to save it. The name of the keystore should end with `.keystore` and give a password for it. Click next.
4. Give the details and click finish.

Comment: "...with .keystore and give a password...", where can I find the password?

Answer (score 2):

That's simple: within the ADT plugin you can extract signed apk just from the IDE. It will ask you for creating a keystore and a key in it. Remember to backup the keystore because it is necessary to upload an update to the market.

See the [section](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) in dev guide.